# Set border color on click

Tags: jquery, html, label

I want to set a border color for the following image when I click the associated label. Can anybody help me? I've tried it with jQuery but it dont worked... Thank you for your help.

```js
$("#fc-goal_1").click(function() {
        $("#fc-goal_1").closest('#fc-goal_1').find('img').css("border", "2px solid rgb(99, 195, 195);");
    });
 $("#fc-goal_2").click(function() {
        $("#fc-goal_2").closest('#fc-goal_1').find('img').css("border", "2px solid rgb(99, 195, 195);");
    });
 $("#fc-goal_3").click(function() {
        $("#fc-goal_3").closest('#fc-goal_1').find('img').css("border", "2px solid rgb(99, 195, 195);");
    });
 $('#fc-goal_4').click(function() {
        $('#fc-goal_4').closest('#fc-goal_1').find('img').css('border', '2px solid rgb(99, 195, 195);');
    });
```

```html
<div class="questions-fc-1 questions-fcm-2 radio-button">
    <input checked="checked" id="muscle-goal_1" name="goal" class="goal" value="1" aria-required="true" type="radio">
    <label id="fc-goal_1" aria-controls="#muscle-goal_1">
        <img style="" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/muskelaufbau.jpg" alt="Blaaaaa">
        <span>Blaaaaa</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="questions-fc-1 questions-fcm-2 radio-button">
    <input checked="checked" id="weight-loss-goal_2" name="goal" class="goal" value="2" aria-required="true" type="radio">
    <label id="fc-goal_2" aria-controls="#weight-loss-goal_2">
        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/abnehmen.jpg" alt="Blaaaaa">
        <span>Blaaaaa</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="questions-fc-1 questions-fcm-2 radio-button">
    <input checked="checked" id="figure-workout-goal_3" name="goal" class="goal" value="3" aria-required="true" type="radio">
    <label id="fc-goal_3" aria-controls="#figure-workout-goal_3">
        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/figurentraining.jpg" alt="Blaaaaa">
        <span>Blaaaaa</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="questions-fc-1 questions-fcm-2 radio-button">
    <input checked="checked" id="health-goal_4" name="goal" class="goal" value="4" aria-required="true" type="radio">
    <label id="fc-goal_4" aria-controls="#health-goal_4">
        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/gesundheit.jpg" alt="Blaaaaa">
        <span>Blaaaaa</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="error_content_box">
    <div style="visibility: hidden;" class="error"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `closest()` call as you're looking up from the element you want to find, so it will never find anything. You also need to remove the trailing `;` in your `css()` value parameter.

Also note that you can easily amend your code to follow better practices, such as DRY, to make it perform better, make it easier to maintain and shorter.

Firstly place a common class on all the `#fc-goal_X` elements, then use a single event handler for all of them using the `this` keyword to reference the element which raised the event. You should also avoid putting inline CSS in your code, whether directly or by calling `css()`. Use classes instead.

> what can I do to make only the checked one with a border color?

In that case you just need to remove the class from all other elements before adding it to the clicked one, like this:

```js
$(".fc-goal").click(function() {
  $(".fc-goal img").removeClass('active');
  $(this).find('img').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: 2px solid rgb(99, 195, 195)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questions-fc-1 questions-fcm-2 radio-button">
  <input checked="checked" id="muscle-goal_1" name="goal" class="goal" value="1" aria-required="true" type="radio">
  <label id="fc-goal_1" class="fc-goal" aria-controls="#muscle-goal_1">
    <img style="" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/muskelaufbau.jpg" alt="Blaaaaa">
    <span>Blaaaaa</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="questions-fc-1 questions-fcm-2 radio-button">
  <input checked="checked" id="weight-loss-goal_2" name="goal" class="goal" value="2" aria-required="true" type="radio">
  <label id="fc-goal_2" class="fc-goal" aria-controls="#weight-loss-goal_2">
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/abnehmen.jpg" alt="Blaaaaa">
    <span>Blaaaaa</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="questions-fc-1 questions-fcm-2 radio-button">
  <input checked="checked" id="figure-workout-goal_3" name="goal" class="goal" value="3" aria-required="true" type="radio">
  <label id="fc-goal_3" class="fc-goal" aria-controls="#figure-workout-goal_3">
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/figurentraining.jpg" alt="Blaaaaa">
    <span>Blaaaaa</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="questions-fc-1 questions-fcm-2 radio-button">
  <input checked="checked" id="health-goal_4" name="goal" class="goal" value="4" aria-required="true" type="radio">
  <label id="fc-goal_4" class="fc-goal" aria-controls="#health-goal_4">
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/gesundheit.jpg" alt="Blaaaaa">
    <span>Blaaaaa</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="error_content_box">
  <div style="visibility: hidden;" class="error"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh okay thanks :) but what can I do to make only the checked one with a border color? You know? So when I click the new one the last one should have no border :s I've tried it but I don't know :(